# Getting the value combinations of multiple select tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So i have 2 select tags one chooses the data type and the other chooses the form of that data.
The first Tag `Données`

```
<select style="display: block;" name="Donnee" id="Donnee" onchange="getComboB(this)" required>
<option value="">Choisir ...</option>
<option value="Alphanumérique">Alphanumérique</option>
<option value="Numérique">Numérique</option>
<option value="Booléen">Booléen</option>
<option value="Date">Date</option>
</select>
```

The second Tag `Saisie`

```
<select style="display: block;" name="Saisie" id="Saisie" onchange="getComboA(this)" required>
<option value="">Choisir ...</option>
<option value="Libre">Valeur Libre</option>
<option value="Multiples">Valeurs Multiples</option>
<option value="Intervalle">Intervalle</option>
</select>
```

I need to get the combination of the two select tags in order to display a certain input. To explain more : If i choose Intervalle in the Saisie select which means interval the type of data can only be only be date or numerique (that's an example). 
So i proceded this way :

```
value_Donnee='';
function getComboB(sel) {
    var value = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value; 
    value_Donnee = value;
    }
function getComboA(sel) {
    var value = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value; 

    if(value == "Libre")
    {
    $("#contain").html('');
    }

    else if(value == "Multiples")
    {
    $("#contain").html('');
    $("#contain").html('Multiples');
    }
    else
    {
    $("#contain").html('');
        if(value_Donnee == "Numérique")
            {
            $("#contain").html('');
            $("#contain").html('Num');
            }
        else if (value_Donnee == "Date")
            {
            $("#contain").html('');
            $("#contain").html('Date');
            }
        else
            {
            $("#contain").html('');
            $("#contain").html('Le type des données ne peut être que Date ou Numérique');
            }

    }

}
```

The problem is that it doesn't take in consideration the getComboB it only takes the first value :/ Any hint. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `#contain`..? Nowhere in your html..

Comment: just a simple div in which i put the result <div id="contain"></div>

Comment: That gives me the value of the selected item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about your logic, but you can try something like that :

```
$('select').change(function(){
    var donnee = $('#Donnee').val();
    var saisie = $('#Saisie').val();

    if(saisie == "Libre")
    {
        $("#contain").html('');
    }
    else if(saisie == "Multiples")
    {
        $("#contain").html('Multiples');
    }
    else
    {
        if(donnee == "Numérique")
        {
            $("#contain").html('Num');
        }
        else if (donnee == "Date")
        {
            $("#contain").html('Date');
        }
        else
        {
            $("#contain").html('Le type des données ne peut être que Date ou Numérique');
        }
    }
});
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Bb6sH/

Comment: well you use jQuery in your solution already don't you? and also you have tagged your question with jQuery

Comment: That's right, I was just emphasizing ;) and this is not my question by the way ;)

Comment: yep sorry I misslead nick name ;-)

Comment: And the problem is not about selecting elements, because in this case functions run, but don't end.

Comment: you mean that Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Bb6sH/ or after moving it to your code? try to explain what is wrong there

Comment: No i'm sorry i had another select in the code that's why i suppose it didn't work. so i made a small change `$('select.needed')` and added the `class="needed"` to the selects that i needed to change. And it worked perfectly. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure that you have a problem with your jquery including path. because I replaced `$("#contain").html` with a simple `alert` and all worked well.

Answer (score 0):

i dont know if this is what you mean but you could try this:

```
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#Donnee, #Saisie'). change(function(){
          $('#contain').html(test());
        });
      });

      function test(){
        var donnee = $('#Donnee option:selected').val();
        var saisie = $('#Saisie option:selected').val();
        if (donnee == 'Numérique'){
          donnee = 'Numérique';
        } else if (donnee == 'Date'){
          donnee = 'Date';
        } else {
          donnee = 'Le type des données ne peut être que Date ou Numérique';
        }
        return saisie + ' ' +donnee;
      }
```